# Altering lines of code in main css and html files for different builds in an angular app

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

In my company, we are using angular 7, and I need to do a build for some different environments.

Some of the time, I'm using the environments files angular provides, but in some other cases I need to change lines in my index.html or styles.css file, where I can't use the environment object.

For example, in some build I'm using cdns for bootstrap, and in others, where I don't have internet, will include it in the bundle of the build.
What I'm doing so far, is just commenting out/in manually, like so :

replace this line :

```
<link rel="stylesheet"   
     href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

with that line:

```
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Is there another/better way? maybe changing the entire index.html file for a certain build?

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest not using a cdn for bootstrap, instead i would install via NPM.

Then if you have other configs that differ for environments you should look at  [Environment Variables](https://alligator.io/angular/environment-variables/).

Edit: To access your environment variables in your html you could do it in this way:

in your-component.ts, import and set the environent variable in a public member like this:

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
export class YourComponent {
   config = environment;
}
```

then in your-component.html, render your variable:

```
<span>{{ config.<your-variable> }}<span>
```

You cannot do it in the css file.

Comment: I do have other configs.Can you write an example of how you would use Environment Variables in html or css file?

Comment: I've updated the answer above on how to access the variables in html.